# Python. Как работет условие < if name: >

Tags: python

Только учусь и не могу найти информации по тому как работает условие.

Например, есть список каких-либо элементов, в том числе пустые / нулевые. И надо создать список, исключающий эти элементы:

```
elems = [(), (), ('',), ('a', 'b'), (), ('a', 'b', 'c'), (1,), (), (), ('d',), ('', ''), ()]

non_empty_elems = [el for el in elems if el]
```

Мне интересно какая химия происходит в части **if el**.

Я понимаю, что делает эта конструкция и что здесь используется булевое значение.

Это значит что питон проверяет "этот элемент существует"? Т.е. в данном случае 1 - существующий элемент (имеющий значение), а 0 - пустое значение? Или это по-другому работает?

Проще говоря, что происходит внутри языка во время выполнения **if el**

Comment: `if el:` -> `if bool(el):` -> `if bool(el) == True:`, а там уже дальше правила преобразования для каждого типа данных свой. Для коллекций `True` будет если коллекция не пустая.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что я хотел узнать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if el:` эквивалентно `if bool(el):`, а дальше смотрим документацию по [стандартным типам](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) данных `Python`:

> **Truth Value Testing**
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use
> in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations
> below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
> that returns zero, when called with the object.
>
> Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`
>
> zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
>
> empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

Ну то есть все объекты по умолчанию рассматриваются как `True`, за исключением:

- `None` и `False`
- `0` любого численного типа
- пустых последовательностей и коллекций

Пояснение, с помощью каких встроенных методов объектов происходят проверки, позволяющие определить, что объект имеет значение `False`:

- либо у него есть метод `__bool__()`, возвращающий `False` (видимо, это случаи `None`, `False` и разных типов числового нуля)
- либо у него есть метод `__len__()`, возвращающий `0` (последовательности и коллекции)

Answer (score -2):

В данном случае у вас список кортежей условие if el стработает если ваш el не равен None.
Пустое множество будь то список, словарь, кортеж тоже вернёт None

Comment: `>>> () == None    # False` 
`>>> () is None    # False`

Comment: `None` тут вообще не при чём. Вы правы только в том, что `bool(None) == False`, а пустые коллекции никакого отношения к `None` не имеют.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю NoneType и пустые / нулевые значения - это разное в питоне. В моем случае именно пустые кортежи, они имеют тип <tuple>,  а None - <NoneType>, т.е. это вообще другой тип данных.
Тем не менее, я хочу понять по какому принципу работает это условие, но мне кажется, что более глубокое объяснение кроется в архитектуре языка, а не его логике и синтаксисе